# How to post data in cURL from parse_ini_file

Tags: php, arrays, curl, post, ini

Integrating SMS Gateway and require to read data in .ini file and perform a POST.

Data as following (include Chinese characters):

```
[101]
DestName=二寶
dstaddr=08881268
smbody=我是測試2
[102]
DestName=小明
dstaddr=08881268
smbody=我是測試3
```

Previous study understand that ***parse_ini_file*** function allowed to read the .ini file and convert it into array such as this `$arr = parse_ini_file($file,true);`

But how to submit these data in cURL Post?

Do I need `http_build_query($arr)` in order to get url string from .ini file?

In cURL, do I need following?

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: multipart/form-data"));
```

or

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes if you wish to post the data to url.
You need to do the following if you are passing the data in array form.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8');
```